# Using `info.position` to find the context menu row view

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

I know I need to find a row in a context menu when long clicking by doing this:

```
  AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        int position = info.position;
```

in `onCreateContextMenu`

How I can I implement it here?  I seem to be only grabbing the FIRST two in this setup.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.comments_context, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Available Actions");

    MenuItem Edit = menu.findItem(R.id.editComment);
    MenuItem Delete = menu.findItem(R.id.deleteComment);

    ReviewUser = ((TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.labelReviewCommentUser)).getText()
            .toString();

    ReviewComment = ((TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.labelReviewComment)).getText()
            .toString();



}
```

I want `ReviewUser` and `ReviewComment` to be selected based on the list row the user clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can I implement it here? I seem to be only grabbing the FIRST
>   two in this setup.

The `v` represents the `View` for which the context menu is built, in this case the `ListView` and not the row view on which you acted. You probably want something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.comments_context, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Available Actions");

    MenuItem Edit = menu.findItem(R.id.editComment);
    MenuItem Delete = menu.findItem(R.id.deleteComment);
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int position = info.position;
    ListView lv = (ListView) v;
    int firstVisible = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View rowView = lv.getChildAt(position - firstVisible);
    ReviewUser = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.labelReviewCommentUser))
            .getText().toString();
    ReviewComment = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.labelReviewComment))
            .getText().toString();
}
```